# Alert the id name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have the following code:

```
<input type="text" id="messageBox" />
```

How will I get the id value? Notice that it is not the `$("#messageBox");` that I want.
I want it to alert the id name of this control. So it should alert the word "messageBox", cus this is the name of the id

Comment: and how are you going to target this input??

Comment: `$(":input").prop("id");`

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of ways to do it.

you can use `prop()` for it:

```
var id = $("input:text").prop("id");
```

or this way:

```
 var id = $("input:text")[0].id;
```

or use `get()`:

```
var id = $("input:text").get(0).id;
```

or you can also use `attr()`:

```
var id = $("input:text").attr('id')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.attr("id")` to select attribute value

```
alert($("input").attr("id"));
alert($("input").prop("id")); 
alert($("input").get(0).id);
alert($("input").attr('id'));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/4njwosL4/)

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrsantharam/4njwosL4/1/)